# Why doesn't R.java find my layout?

Tags: android

[image]

The image shows it all. Although I have a `task.xml`, the `R.java` class can not find it. This is the view for each of my list items. Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? Project --> Clean...

Comment: @codeMagic absolutely !

Comment: getLayoutInflater() vs LayoutInflater.from(ctx) maybe?

Comment: @mirco.widmer not sure if `BaseAdapter` has that method. Sorry if I didnt make that clear :)

Answer (score 1):

I think in your code U must have imported .R file...
For example import com.d.maulik.R .. Remove this import and then save and ctrl+space.. this will work i guess.

Comment: Oooh .. it auto-imported `android.R` ... I **need** to import my own R file. com.example.troll.derp.R FIXED!!!!

Comment: If you dont import your own .R file and remove auto imported android.R .. the problem will be fixed. by clean & build