# R cannot be resolved-Android error

Tags: android, android-activity

Hey everybody i know this question has been asked many times before.
i have tried all the possible solutions given but i still havent been able to get the solution.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.newp;
import com.example.newp.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

}
```

PS: Ive tried cleaning my project. I removed import android.R; 
Its still not working. Please help out. Im unable to progress forward because of this bug.

Comment: Check again. Make sure no errors in xml etc. This error, while annoying, is caused by few possibilities.

Comment: make sure you don't have errors on your xml..  example using uppercase letters for you layout names

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279379/why-doesnt-r-java-find-my-layout

Comment: Check your string resource values. Sometimes there is an error that doesn't show in eclipse. As always, clean project before running it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Make sure that your `activity_main` file doesn't have any compilations errors (Red marks) before you follow these steps.

First remove the line

```
import com.example.newp.R;
```

Still error persists, then make a single line comment to `setContenView();`

```
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Now clean the project from menu Project -> clean.

Remove comment line to `setContentView()`.

Now check that you don't have any errors.

If problem persists, restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Check your res folder. If you have resources errors, than fix them and after that try Project->Clean.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty handy [guide](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/a-comprehensive-troubleshooting-guide-for-androids-r-cannot-be-resolved-error/?alertspromo=100904&ftag=&s_cid=rSINGLE&tag=nl.rSINGLE&ttag=rSINGLE) that provides a lot of possible solutions to the `R` problems.